# Namespace error when using T4MVC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, t4mvc

Just heard about T4MVC but i can't get it to work in my sample project (ASP.NET MVC 2, Visual Studio 2008).

I get the following erros when trying to build the project:

> Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Account' does not exist in the namespace 'Northwind.Web.MVC' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Bruno\Documents\My Dropbox\Projetos.NET\Northwind\Northwind.Web.MVC\AccountController.generated.cs 38 61 Northwind.Web.MVC

This is where the error occurs:

```
[GeneratedCode("T4MVC", "2.0"), DebuggerNonUserCode]
public AccountController Actions { get { return MVC.Account; } }
```

I really hate magic strings, so please help me to make it work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a namespace conflict between T4MVC and your code.  Go to T4MVC.settings.t4 and find this code:

```
// The prefix used for things like MVC.Dinners.Name and MVC.Dinners.Delete(Model.DinnerID)
const string HelpersPrefix = "MVC";
```

Just change "MVC" to something else and you'll be on your way :)

Alternatively, you could rename your namespace if you prefer (Northwind.Web.**MVC**)

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem but I had to delete all sub-files from T4MVC.tt first and then rebuild them by right clicking on T4MVC.tt and Select "Run Custom Tool"

Comment: I had the same issue and it was because I'd named an MVC area "System". Renaming it corrected the problem.